# Is there a way to send data via push notification that contains instruction for the system and does not require user input?

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications, amazon-sns, pubnub

I am wondering if it possible to use push notifications as a way to give instruction to a device that requires not user input? Basically, I want to send a push notification to a network access device with a command, have the device perform the action, and then send back a response on whether it was a success of failure? Is this possible using push notifications?

Comment: Also, is it possible to use Apple Push Notification service with a lunix device?

Comment: Push notifications infra are restricted to the devices of the provider. Apple only works with Apple devices, not Linux. If I understand you well, you should basically deploy a special service (Like an XMPP server) and have your Linux devices / applications connected as clients.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible, but that will depend on the type of receiver/device you are using.

For example, SNS can call an Http endpoint, and that endpoint could do as little or as much work as you want it to do and then send a response (perhaps another Sns/sqs message) back to the caller.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SendMessageToHttp.html